# Javascript for CRM 2016 phones

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics

I would like to ask about CRM Javascript code for phones, for example I have the following JS(Javascript) code for CRM web application it's not working with CRM phones

```
function checkCurrentUserInTeam(teamId) {

var serverUrl = "https://" + window.location.host;

var userId = Xrm.Page.context.getUserId();

if (teamId != null) {

    var fwdFilter = "TeamMembershipSet?$filter=TeamId eq guid'" + teamId + "' and SystemUserId eq guid'" + userId + "'";
    var url = serverUrl  + "/xrmservices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/" + fwdFilter;
    var fwdResult = GetOdataResults(url).results;

    if (fwdResult != null && fwdResult.length > 0) {
        return true;

    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}
return false;
}

function GetOdataResults(url) {
    CallOData(url);
    str = CallOData(url);
    var data = eval('(' + str + ')');
    return data.d;
}

function CallOData(url) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-Width", "XMLHttpRequest");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*");
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    return xmlhttp.responseText;

}
```

I'm using checkCurrentUserInTeam function with team ID as parameter, and the error I think when XMLHttpRequest call the page in phones (See the below pic) .

[Click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P0n5.png)

I need your help if you have a specially code for CRM phones or some library for it. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the way you are creating your `serverUrl`. Try using [getClientUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334511.aspx#BKMK_getclienturl) instead.

`var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl()`

Comment: @MajedAl-Omair, Happy to help, typically on Stack sites, if an answer was helpful you should accept or up vote it. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)